# TypeError when using $resource in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I've got a weird error in angularjs. I've used $resource module in angularjs to make rest requests by registering this service

```
$provide.service("CustomerService", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/com/caspco/customers/:url:id', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, params: {id: '@id'}},
        find: { method: 'POST', isArray: true ,params:{url:'search'}},
        .......... other actions ..........
    });
}]);
```

in the rest server side I have a search method with the above url of `find` action that returns a json array. when I what to call `find` action by this way in the controller :

```
service.$find().$promise.$then(function (res) {
    console.log("resource is" + res);
}, function (error) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

It raises

```
TypeError: (anonymous function) angular.js:2070
(anonymous function) angular.js:1516
k.$apply angular.js:2575
(anonymous function) angular.js:4323
o.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
r.handle
```

Comment: Any more details about the error ...

Comment: have you included angular-resources JS file?

Comment: @Eylen Yes! I've included

Comment: @Пуя: It doesn't help much to use minified version when debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Methods on the service are not prefixed by the '$' character.  Methods on resources returned from the service are prefixed by '$'.  The 'then' method on the $promise property is also not prefixed by '$'.

I think if you clean up that syntax you will be on the right track.

See [the angular docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

Comment: Problem occurred on the response of the server

Comment: And occurred only on response of the services with the array response

Answer (score 0):

First off your code to call the service should be:

```
service.find().$promise.then(function (res) {
  console.log("resource is" + res);
}, function (error) {
  console.log("error");
});
```

The next thing to check, is your response actually an array. I got caught out big time with this, I was calling a service to get a list of objects from the backend, but before returning them, the backend was wrapping them inside a Response object, so what angular received was not an array, it was an object with an array inside it.